# How to use .promise( ) on a .on( ) event listener?

Tags: jquery

I have a .on() listener for a 'fetch' event. Is there an easy way that I can fire an event when it finishes?

```
      this.on('fetch', function() {
           log('fetch event started!!');
       });

       // fetch event ended???
```

I have been playing around with .promise() but I am not getting good results.

UPDATE - Here is my code I am tapping into the fetch event for a collection so I can show/hide loading icons and do some other work.

```
   var tweetList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: tweetModel,
            // used for collection.sort() 
            comparator: function (item) {
                return item.get("CreatedDate");
            },
            initialize: function(models, options) {
                this.on('fetch', function() {
                    console.log('fetch event started!!');

                });

            },
            fetch: function(options) {
                this.trigger('fetch', this, options);
                return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
            }
        });
```

I tried binding another event to fetch but it doesn't look like it's firing correctly.

```
 var tweetList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: tweetModel,
            // used for collection.sort() 
            comparator: function (item) {
                return item.get("SortOrder");
            },
            initialize: function(models, options) {
                this.on('fetch', function(m, o) {
                    log(o.status);

                });

            },
            fetch: function(options) {
                this.trigger('fetch', this, { status: "started"});
                this.trigger('fetch', this, { status: "ended"});
                return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: what are you fetching? how is it being fetched? can you show that code?

Comment: What does the code for the `fetch` event do? If there's nothing asynchronous you could just put something like `$(this).trigger('fetchcomplete');` at the end, then bind an event handler for `fetchcomplete` on that same element. Even if it *is* asynchronous, you could probably do the same thing, to be honest.

Comment: calling `.on()` on `promise`  ? is that what you want ? why you don't use  `.done()` callback

Comment: You want to fire an event after this event handler runs?  You can bind *another* `fetch` event.  They will be ran in the order bound.  Or you can have the event handler trigger the function.  Events do not implement `promise`.

Answer (score 1):

using Q (https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and jQuery you could do something like this potentially...

```
this.on('fetch', function() {
           console.log('fetch event started!!');
        Q($.ajax(...)).then(function () {
            console.log("fetch event ended...");
        });
       });
```

Alternatively, here's an example with just using jQuery...

```
this.on('fetch', function() {
    console.log('fetch event started!!');
    $.when( $.ajax(...) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.log('fetch event ended...');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this would have to be my last resort. I already have enough libraries as it is.

Comment: are you using jQuery? It returns promises from ajax calls natively without the need for Q...